# What is the effect of giving ColorFunctionScaling a numerical argument?

Tags: plotting, color, undocumented

(by making a mistake) I realised that `ColorFunctionScaling` can take a list of numerical arguments rather than just booleans. The following is true for `ContourPlot` and `DensityPlot` but not `Plot3D` and haven't searched further. The first argument seems to affect the endpoint values of the scaling and the second argument the gradient (although not entirely sure about this statement). Anyway, here's what I mean:

```
GraphicsGrid@Table[ContourPlot[x, {x, 0, 2}, {y, -1, 1}, 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> {i, j},
   Frame -> False], 
{i, -1, 2, .5}, {j, -1, 2, .5}]
```

[image]

My questions are:

- Is this a feature?
- How, if at all, can I control it accurately in a way that two contour plots, say `ContourPlot[x, {x, 0, 2}, {y, -1, 1}]` and `ContourPlot[x, {x, -2, 0}, {y, -1, 1}]` can have a common colour reference without resorting to redefining the `ColorFunction` and setting the scaling to false?
- Does it affect other plotting functions?

Comment: `Framed@GraphicsGrid@Table[
     ContourPlot[x, {x, 0, 2}, {y, -1, 1},
      Frame -> False,
      PlotLabel -> {i, j}, Contours -> 40,
      ImageSize -> 200,
      ##
      ]
     ,
     {i, -2, 2, 2}, {j, -2, 2, 2}
     ] & @@@ {
  {ColorFunctionScaling -> {i, j}, ColorFunction -> (Hue[#] &)},
  {ColorFunction -> (Hue[(j - i) #] &)}
  
  }` but don't ask me why.

Comment: AHA!!! But... WHY!?!?!? And also, why just Contour/Density plots (because one argument passed to colorfunction?).

Comment: And what have I told you at the end? :P

Comment: Also, this only works for integer values (fractional values are different. Which begs the question... WHY!?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nice find.  I think that this is simply giving the equivalent of a [`DataRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DataRange.html) over the *z* (density) values.  Put another way it is providing the third parameter of [`Rescale`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rescale.html):

[image]

That lets us conveniently do something like this:

```
DensityPlot[
  x, {x, -12, 0}, {y, -1, 1}
  , ColorFunctionScaling -> {385, 745}
  , ColorFunction -> "VisibleSpectrum"
]
```

[image]

Correlation with `Rescale`:

```
Rescale[Range[-12, 0, 1/2], {-12, 0}, {385, 745}]

ColorData["VisibleSpectrum"] /@ % // Row
```

> ```
> {385, 400, 415, 430, 445, 460, 475, 490, 505, 520, 535, 550, 565,
>  580, 595, 610, 625, 640, 655, 670, 685, 700, 715, 730, 745}
> ```

[image]

The behavior exists within the low level `` Visualization`Core`DensityPlot `` function:

```
Visualization`Core`DensityPlot[x, {x, -12, 0}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> {385, 745}, ColorFunction -> "VisibleSpectrum"]
```

This is a non-end-user-readable function so I will have difficulty tracking it further.  However if anyone has a counterexample to my supposition above please let me know and I shall attempt to revise my conjecture.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer (+1). So then this means this is useless right? In the sense that it has overlapping functionality with `ScalingFunction` which is more versatile i.e. in this example, you can set `ColorFunctionScaling->False` and replicate the same result with `ScalingFunctions -> {None, None, (365/12 # + 745) &}`

Comment: @gpap I wouldn't say it is useless.  Lots of things can be done in many different ways, especially in *Mathematica*.  This doesn't make all but one method useless.  One could also use `ColorFunctionScaling -> True` and `ColorFunction -> (ColorData["VisibleSpectrum"][385 + 360 #] &)`.

Comment: I agree, what I meant is that the option has limited functionality whereas both alternatives can do that and much more. In any case, this seems to be the answer so tick for you. Thanks again!